# Can't bind array

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

```
[HttpPost("notify")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Notify([FromBody] int [] ids)
{
   return Ok();
}
```

Request payload:

```
{ ids: [1, 2, 3]}
```

`ids` parameter is null.

If I change `ids` to type `object`, it's concret type is `JObject`.

What am I missing?

Comment: what says the debug console at chrome? how looks the complete send ?

Comment: @tire0011 the payload is just like the snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payload in the question is an object with a property called `ids`, but the signature is for an array. Thus, I changed the Javascript to directly post an (anonymous) array...

```
axios.post("lalala", this.props.items.map(function (s) { return s.id }))
```